# Sqlplus print category with subcategories

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I have tables set up like this:

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES (1000, 'Type1', 'A', '01-Jan-21', 27.00);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES (1010, 'Type2', 'A',  '01-Jan-21', 30.00);
INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES (1020, 'Type3', 'A', '07-Jan-21', 0.00);

INSERT INTO SUBCATEGORY VALUES (1010, 1010, 'ABC', '01-Jan-21', 2000.00);
INSERT INTO SUBCATEGORY VALUES (1010, 1020, 'ABC', '07-Jan-21', 0.00);
INSERT INTO SUBCATEGORY VALUES (1020, 1010, 'XYZ', '01-Jan-21', 1000.00);
```

And I want them to display like:

```
   CATCODE NAME  C CDATE        DECIMAL
---------- ----- - --------- ----------
      1000 Type1 A 01-JAN-21       2527
      1010 Type2 A 01-JAN-21       3000
   CATCODE    SUBCODE NAME     SDATE    DECIMAL
---------- ---------- ---- --------- ----------
      1010       1010 ABC  01-JAN-21       2000
      1010       1020 ABC  07-JAN-21          0
   CATCODE NAME  C CDATE        DECIMAL
---------- ----- - --------- ----------
      1020 Type3 A 07-JAN-21          0
   CATCODE    SUBCODE NAME     SDATE    DECIMAL
---------- ---------- ---- --------- ----------
      1020       1010 XYZ  01-JAN-21       1000
```

So basically it posts all the columns for the category table, and if that category has a subcategory (related by CATCODE), it will post the columns for the subcategory table underneath.

I've experimented around with different combinations of JOINs and UNION trying to get the result outlined above, but quite frankly I don't know that I'm approaching this correctly. UNION I don't think can't work because of the mismatched data types.

Comment: Please edit question to add the following: **1.** create statements for tables **2.** an example of what you have tried **3.** expected output in [table format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using Oracle SQL MODEL clause.
With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    category AS
        (
            Select 1000 "CAT_CODE", 'Type1' "CAT_NAME", 'A' "C", To_Date('01-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy') "C_DATE", 27.00 "DECIM" From Dual Union All
            Select 1010, 'Type2', 'A',  To_Date('01-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy'), 30.00 From Dual Union All
            Select 1020, 'Type3', 'A', To_Date('07-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy'), 0.00 From Dual 
        ),
    sub_category AS
        (
            Select 1010 "CAT_CODE", 1010 "SUB_CODE", 'ABC' "SUB_NAME", To_Date('01-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy') "S_DATE", 2000.00 "DECIM" From Dual Union All
            Select 1010, 1020, 'ABC', To_Date('07-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy'), 0.00 From Dual Union All
            Select 1020, 1010, 'XYZ', To_Date('01-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy'), 1000.00 From Dual  
        ),
```

... create CTE (I named it out_model) using MODEL clause to define the rows of your report with all the values that we are going to use for main sql and final report ...

```sql
  out_model AS
    (
          SELECT    ROW_STR, SUB_ROW_STR, ID, CASE WHEN SUB_ROW_STR Is Null THEN IDX ELSE IDX END "IDX", COUNT_IDX, 
                    CAT_CODE, CAT_NAME, C, C_DATE, C_DECIM, SUB_CODE, SUB_NAME, S_DATE, S_DECIM
          FROM  (
                    Select  CAST(Null As VarChar2(255)) "ROW_STR", CAST('-' As VarChar2(255)) "SUB_ROW_STR", CAST(0 As Number(6)) "ID", CAST(0 As Number(6)) "S_ID",
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.CAT_CODE ORDER BY c.CAT_CODE) "IDX", Count(s.CAT_CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY c.CAT_CODE) "COUNT_IDX",
                            To_Char(c.CAT_CODE) "CAT_CODE", c.CAT_NAME, c.C, To_Char(c.C_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') "C_DATE", To_Char(c.DECIM, '999G990D00') "C_DECIM",
                            To_Char(s.SUB_CODE) "SUB_CODE", s.SUB_NAME, To_Char(s.S_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') "S_DATE", To_Char(s.DECIM, '999G990D00') "S_DECIM"
                    From category c
                    Left Join sub_category s ON(s.CAT_CODE = c.CAT_CODE)
                ) 
              MODEL Partition By(CAT_CODE)
                    Dimension By(IDX, COUNT_IDX)
                    Measures    (ID, S_ID, ROW_STR, SUB_ROW_STR, CAT_NAME, C, C_DATE, C_DECIM, SUB_CODE, SUB_NAME, S_DATE, S_DECIM)
                    RULES   (   ROW_STR[1, ANY] =  CASE WHEN ID[CV(), CV()] = 0 THEN LPAD(CV(CAT_CODE), 10, ' ') || ' ' || RPAD(CAT_NAME[CV(), CV()], 10, ' ') || ' ' || C[CV(), CV()] || '  ' || RPAD(C_DATE[CV(), CV()], 12, ' ') || ' ' || LPAD(C_DECIM[CV(), CV()], 12, ' ') END,
                                ROW_STR[1, -5] = CASE WHEN CV(IDX) = 1 THEN '  CAT_CODE' || ' ' || 'CAT_NAME  ' || ' ' || 'C' || '  ' || 'CAT_DATE    ' || ' ' || '   CAT_DECIM' END,
                                --
                                ROW_STR[1, -4] =  CASE WHEN CV(IDX) = 1 THEN '----------' || ' ' || '----------' || ' ' || '-' || '  ' || '------------' || ' ' || '------------' END,
                                ROW_STR[500, 500] = CASE WHEN CV(IDX) = CV(COUNT_IDX) THEN '          ' || ' ' || 'SUB_CODE  ' || ' ' || 'SUB_NAME    ' || 'SUB_DATE    ' || ' ' || '   SUB_DECIM' END, 
                                ROW_STR[600, 600] =  CASE WHEN CV(IDX) = CV(COUNT_IDX) THEN '          ' || ' ' || '----------' || ' ' || '------------' || ' ' || '------------' || ' ' || '------------' END,
                                SUB_ROW_STR[ANY, ANY] =  CASE WHEN SUB_CODE[CV(), CV()] Is Not Null And ID[CV(), CV()] = 0 THEN '          ' || ' ' || LPAD(SUB_CODE[CV(), CV()], 10, ' ') || ' ' || RPAD(SUB_NAME[CV(), CV()], 10, ' ') || RPAD(S_DATE[CV(), CV()], 12, ' ') || ' ' || LPAD(S_DECIM[CV(), CV()], 12, ' ') END
                            )
          ORDER BY CAT_CODE, COUNT_IDX, IDX
    )
```

Main SQL with the resulting report...

```sql
SELECT  CASE WHEN ROWNUM > 1 And SUBSTR(p.ROW_STR, 1, 10) = '  CAT_CODE' THEN Chr(10) || p.ROW_STR ELSE p.ROW_STR END "REPORT"
FROM    (   SELECT  ROW_STR "ROW_STR", CAT_CODE, 
                    SUB_CODE, IDX "IDX", COUNT_IDX
            FROM    out_model
          UNION ALL
            SELECT  SUB_ROW_STR, CAT_CODE, SUB_CODE,IDX +10000, COUNT_IDX
            FROM out_model
        ) p
WHERE ROW_STR Is Not Null And (COUNT_IDX < 500 OR (COUNT_IDX >= 500 And Nvl((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sub_category WHERE CAT_CODE = p.CAT_CODE), 0) > 0))
ORDER BY
    CAT_CODE, IDX, COUNT_IDX

/*  R e s u l t :
REPORT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------
  CAT_CODE CAT_NAME   C  CAT_DATE        CAT_DECIM            
---------- ---------- -  ------------ ------------            
      1000 Type1      A  01.01.2021          27.00            

  CAT_CODE CAT_NAME   C  CAT_DATE        CAT_DECIM           
---------- ---------- -  ------------ ------------           
      1010 Type2      A  01.01.2021          30.00           
           SUB_CODE   SUB_NAME    SUB_DATE        SUB_DECIM  
           ---------- ------------ ------------ ------------ 
                 1010 ABC       01.01.2021       2,000.00    
                 1020 ABC       07.01.2021           0.00    

  CAT_CODE CAT_NAME   C  CAT_DATE        CAT_DECIM           
---------- ---------- -  ------------ ------------           
      1020 Type3      A  07.01.2021           0.00           
           SUB_CODE   SUB_NAME    SUB_DATE        SUB_DECIM  
           ---------- ------------ ------------ ------------ 
                 1010 XYZ       01.01.2021       1,000.00   
*/
```